# Resize SpTBX dockable panel's caption

Tags: delphi, sptbxlib

`TSpTBXDockablePanel` class has no property to change caption height. Caption is top area with [x] button. It has read-only property

```
property CaptionPanelSize: TPoint read GetCaptionPanelSize;
```

but I cannot change this caption height. How to change it?

I tried to make `SetCaptionPanelSize()` for this property, then change `FPanel.Height`. But setting height has no effect.

Comment: Isn't that determined by the system, it being standard windows non client area?

Answer (score -1):

I found it later. It is option `Options.TitleBarMaxSize`. If it's big, then code scales it to bigger value on Hi-DPI. I needed to scale it.